# Pick a column value based on column index stored in another column (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have four columns:
Column1, Column2, Column3, ind

```
import pandas as pd


tbl = {
        'Column1':['Spark',10000,'Python','35days'],
        'Column2' :[500,'PySpark',22000,30000],
        'Column3':['30days','40days','35days','pandas'],
        'ind':[1,2,1,3]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(tbl)
```

Does anyone know is there a way to add a new column without loop that will gather values from first 3 columns based on index stored in 'ind' column?

'Course':['Spark','PySpark','Python','pandas']

I've tried some combinations with iloc, lambda and apply but failed.

Expected output:

```
  Column1  Column2 Column3  ind   Course
0   Spark      500  30days    1    Spark
1   10000  PySpark  40days    2  PySpark
2  Python    22000  35days    1   Python
3  35days    30000  pandas    3   pandas
```

Comment: Can you show some expected results? And why you can't use a loop?

Comment: how do you chose whether "Spark" or "30days" should be picked?

Comment: 'ind' column indicates from which column to pick a value for particular row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For efficiency, use the official [lookup by index/column labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
import numpy as np
idx, cols = pd.factorize('Column'+df['ind'].astype(str))
df['Course'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

output:

```
  Column1  Column2 Column3  ind   Course
0   Spark      500  30days    1    Spark
1   10000  PySpark  40days    2  PySpark
2  Python    22000  35days    1   Python
3  35days    30000  pandas    3   pandas
```

###### timings

performed on 40k rows

```
# lookup (this answer)
25.6 ms ± 2.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# apply
722 ms ± 48.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try `apply` on rows

```py
df['Course'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.iloc[row['ind']-1], axis=1)
```

Or you can try

```py
df['Course'] = df.values[np.arange(len(df['ind'])), df['ind'].sub(1)]
```

```
print(df)

  Column1  Column2 Column3  ind   Course
0   Spark      500  30days    1    Spark
1   10000  PySpark  40days    2  PySpark
2  Python    22000  35days    1   Python
3  35days    30000  pandas    3   pandas
```

Comment: @Delfori apply is really not ideal for this task (will be at least one order of magnitude slower than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72321262/16343464) for large dataframes)